# Update, insert, remove, maximum, add value to each element in O(log(N))

Tags: data-structures

I need a data structure that associates a key to a value(both integers) and that is able to do the following in `O(log(N))`:

1.Remove a key.

2.Add an integer to all the existing values.

3.Get maximum value.

4.Add a new key or update an existing one.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to iterate over all exisiting values in O(log(N)) time, so 2 is basically impossible.

Comment: I was thinking maybe to have a tree structure and to remember sums on intervals of keys.

Comment: I don't think I understand how that would help, the sums would be out of sync with the real values, no?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention a programming language, but something like the TreeMap in Java should suit your needs. It's a red-black tree combined with a Key-Value scheme. 
It keeps your Keys sorted at all times.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

It has O(log(N)) for removing, updating, inserting and retrieving. However iterating the whole Tree will always be O(N) unfortunately so 2 is impossible.